# Correct VirtualDocumentRoot directive

Tags: apache-http-server, localhost, virtual-host

What should be the correct value for the VirtualDocumentRoot directive if I have the following folder structure:

```
/example.com/
/example.co.uk/
```

and wanted to be able to access it using either `example.com.localdev` or `www.example.co.uk.localdev`

I have tried the following conf but it fails:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  UseCanonicaName Off
  ServerAlias *.localdev
  VirtualDocumentRoot "E:/workspace/%-2+/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

and host file has been configured using AcrylicDNS: `127.0.0.1 *.localdev`